# Box2d and Cocos2d on iOS issues with sprites and positioning

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I am creating new sprites/bodies when touching the screen:

```
-(void) addNewSpriteAtPosition:(CGPoint)pos
{
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    bodyDef.position=[Helper toMeters:pos];
    b2Body* body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    b2CircleShape circle;
    circle.m_radius = 30/PTM_RATIO;

    // Define the dynamic body fixture.
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape=&circle;
    fixtureDef.density=0.7f;
    fixtureDef.friction=0.3f;
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.5;
    body-> CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

    PhysicsSprite* sprite = [PhysicsSprite spriteWithFile:@"circle.png"];
    [self addChild:sprite];
    [sprite setPhysicsBody:body];
    body->SetUserData((__bridge void*)sprite);
}
```

Here is my positioning helper:

```
+(b2Vec2) toMeters:(CGPoint)point
{
    return b2Vec2(point.x / PTM_RATIO, point.y / PTM_RATIO);
}
```

PhysicsSprite is the typical one used with Box2D, but I'll include the relevant method:

```
-(CGAffineTransform) nodeToParentTransform
{
    b2Vec2 pos = physicsBody->GetPosition();

    float x = pos.x * PTM_RATIO;
    float y = pos.y * PTM_RATIO;

    if (ignoreAnchorPointForPosition_)
    {
        x += anchorPointInPoints_.x;
        y += anchorPointInPoints_.y;
    }

    float radians = physicsBody->GetAngle();
    float c = cosf(radians);
    float s = sinf(radians);

    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(anchorPointInPoints_, CGPointZero))
    {
        x += c * -anchorPointInPoints_.x + -s * -anchorPointInPoints_.y;
        y += s * -anchorPointInPoints_.x + c * -anchorPointInPoints_.y;
    }

    self.position = CGPointMake(x, y);

    // Rot, Translate Matrix
    transform_ = CGAffineTransformMake(c, s, -s, c, x, y);
    return transform_;
}
```

Now, I have two issues illustrated by the following two images, which show the debug draw with the sprites. Retina and non-retina versions:

[image: retina]

[image: non-retina]

Issue #1 - As you can see in both images, the further away from (0,0) the objects are, the sprite becomes further offset from the physics body.

Issue #2 - The red circle image files are 60x60 (retina), and the white circles are 30x30 (non-retina). Why are they sized differently on screen? Cocos2d should use points, not pixels, so shouldn't they be the same size on screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of hardcoded size, use contentSize.

```
circle.m_radius = sprite.contentSize.width*0.5f/PTM_RATIO;
```

This works in all SD and Retina mode.

You can use this style to sync between box2d and cocos2d positions:

```
body->SetTransform([self toB2Meters:sprite.position], 0.0f);    //box2d<---cocos2d

//OR
sprite.position = ccp(body->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO,
                     body->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);  //box2d--->cocos2d
```

Comment: Regarding the contentSize - your code results in the non-retina physics body being the same size as the non-retina sprite, which is good. However, while about 9 circles fill the width of the screen in retina mode, about 18 fill the screen in non-retina mode. It should be 9 on each so that the experience is the same. I still don't understand why this happens. In typical iOS dev, a 30 point radius is the same in either mode, you just get higher res in retina mode.

Comment: And regarding the sync code, does that require manual updating of the positioning in every frame? I was hoping for that to be self-contained in the PhysicsSprite. In other words, where do I put that code?

Comment: Sorry I used simply custom CCSprite with b2body member and overridden update function. Your's something else problem then...

Comment: would you be able to post your sprite class? I'm desperate to get this working and will try anything (been trying for over a week now).

Comment: yes..from laserManager class, and manager's update is called from main game scene: tick method. I used only one tick method is game.